# Is there a Javascript method that will achieve concatenation of nested parenthesis?

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation

I am trying to create a string from input but formatted in a unique way.

Inputs will be single words: `word1`

The string will be empty until the first input comes then the string `myString` will be `+(-word1)`.

For the second input: `word2`, `myString` needs to now look like:

```
    +(-word1+(-word2))
```

For clarity, a third input: `word3`, `myString` will now be:

```
    +(-word1+(-word2+(-word3)))
```

I believe this is going to require something a little more clever than normal string concatenation. I would prefer to not use a loop.

### Is there a native Javascript (or potentially JQuery) function that can accomplish creating a string like this?

Here is what I have done

```
    var myString = '';

    function someFunction()
    { 
     ...

      var inputString = document.getElementById('my-input').value;
      myString = myString + "+(" + "-" + inputString + ")";
    }
```

However this is producing

```
    +(-word1)+(-word2)
```

This makes sense because the strings are just being concatenated in the function, what needs to happen rather is a sort of insertion. Is there a Javascript method that could make this insertion easier?  Perhaps something like inserting the new string at the second to last space of the current string? However it's not an array so I don't know best practices here.

Comment: The problem is that getting from `+(-word1+(-word2))` to `+(-word1+(-word2+(-word3)))` cannot be done via concatenation, since the first is not a substring of the second. You'll have to do more complicated manipulation. As you noted, you'll have to insert the new string inside the previous string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for the first closing parentesis and replace the value.

```js
const insert = (s, v) => s ? s.replace(/(?=\))/, `+(-${v})`) : `+(-${v})`;

console.log(['word1', 'word2', 'word3'].reduce(insert, undefined));
```

Comment: What does `undefined` do/mean here?

Comment: it is just a falsy value to denote the start of the nesting structure.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the prettiest way to do this, but you could use a map on the list of words....

```js
const words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

let result = '+' + words.map(w => `(-${w}+`).join('').replace(/\+$/, '') + ''.padStart(words.length, ')')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Array.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) method fit well for this problem if you can store the successive inputs into an array:

```js
const words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];

let res = words.reduceRight((s, word) => `+(-${word}${s})`, "");

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah, but you see, normal string concatenation can be quite clever indeed.

Quick and dirty, all you needed to do was place `+(-` between each and append the final parentheses. Hehe...

```js
arr = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3' ];
console.log( '+(-' + arr.join('+(-') + ')'.repeat(arr.length) );
```

Alternatively use .map

```js
arr = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3' ];

console.log(
  arr.map( (e) => `+(-${e}` ) +
  ')'.repeat(arr.length)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use a count variable to store how many words are added then slice the string up to the point when only closing brackets remain.

insert your new word

add the remaining string

```
var myString = '';
var count = 0
    function someFunction()
    { 
     ...
      count++;
      var inputString = document.getElementById('my-input').value;
      myString = myString.slice(0,0-count) + "+(" + "-" + inputString + ")" + myString.slice(0-count);
    }
```